# How can I use the IntelliJ autocomplete feature in property files in the community edition

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, application.properties

I am trying to insert some values into the `application.properties` file while following a video tutorial. In the tutorial, there is code completion while typing some values into the property file. But my IntelliJ community edition is not allowing me to use the autocomplete feature. Please how can I achieve this?

Comment: This functionality is available only in IntelliJ Ultimate.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64424533/) autocomplete feature for property files are available just in ultimate edition but if you want to use autocomplete in community edition you can use plugins like [Spring boot assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17747-spring-boot-assistant) or [Spring boot helper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18622-spring-boot-helper)