# Spring Boot Application.properties has no autocomplete suggestions

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm a spring boot beginner
I created a sample project using the spring initializer
in the application.properties I want to change the server. port but editor doesn't know that
doesn't know anything at all
what's the problem

Comment: including details of your editor would help here.

Comment: hi,i'm using intellij community edition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community Edition of IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support autocompletion for application.properties. It is an Ultimate edition feature.

From [this support thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006882520-Java-Spring-application-properties-Code-Completion-not-working):

> Spring Boot framework is available in the **Ultimate** edition of IntelliJ IDEA only. It comes as a bundled plugin and is enabled by default.

Comment: i thought that's problem

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ community edition doesn't support spring boot hence you don't have autocompletion, its an "enterprise" feature (read supported only in the IntelliJ enterprise edition).

All-in-all, there is a special JSON file that IntelliJ can parse (again, only the enterprise edition) and based on the information found in this file it can produce auto-completion for the properties / YAML configuration files.

You can also create such a JSON for your own configuration files by using an annotation processor:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

See [this tutorial](https://www.mdoninger.de/2015/05/16/completion-for-custom-properties-in-spring-boot.html) for example, there are many others. But again, this all works only in the enterprise edition of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

##### Hello

There is a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition which might be very helpful with autocomplete and few more things, here is it's website: [Spring Boot Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17747-spring-boot-assistant).
You can get the plugin from the link above or directly from the IDE:

- go to File -> Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S on Windows)

  search for "Plugins"

  go to Marketplace

  search for "Spring Boot Assistant"

  install it and restart your IDE

  enjoy autocomplete

Hope it will help you learning, keep working, mate :D

Comment: Hey, do you know any plugin forn autocompletition while I typing in JPARepositoty for community edition? (like the one we got in the ultimate)

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for the autocomplete feature on the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, there is a plugin for that found [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21530-wl-spring-assistant).

> This plugin adds auto-completion support for Spring Boot configuration files (application.yml, application.properties).

I have tested it and it is working ok as shared in the [image: screenshot]