# application.properties not showing values set by @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml

There's a tutorial in the book that I'm reading about application.properties having the capability of using intellisense to find properties of a class when @ConfigurationProperties is set.  However, it's not working when I try it.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Main class:

```
package com.hecklers.sburrestdemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class SburRestDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SburRestDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Greeting class:
package com.hecklers.sburrestdemo;

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "greeting")
class Greeting {
    private String name;
    private String coffee;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCoffee() {
        return coffee;
    }

    public void setCoffee(String coffee) {
        this.coffee = coffee;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hecklers</groupId>
    <artifactId>sbur-rest-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sbur-rest-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your all above 3 classes are correct. You didn't shared how you are using these properties. But as sample i am giving.
In your **Controller** class you can use like this.

```
@Autowired Greeting greeting;
```

and return getName() like this.

```
greeting.getName();
```

You can set properties in application.properties like this.

```
greeting.name = rds80
```

Comment: my question was more how about why the intellisense wasn't showing in application.properties. The author said that's the benefit of using ConfigurationProperties instead of @Value.  So after typing greeting, I should see intellisense for "name" and "coffee"

Comment: So like in your java class you want to see autoComplete in your application.properties like when you type greeting. you want to see name and coffee right?

Comment: That's correct.  According to the author of the book, I should see the properties as autocomplete for the Greeting class.

Comment: No that will not will happen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64424533/spring-boot-application-properties-has-no-autocomplete-suggestions  check this i am using intelij ide community edition will not support this autocomplete feature. it depends on IDE feature.

Comment: https://copilot.github.com/ you can use this plugin for autocomplete.